# Creating Barcharts in Laravel 5.6 using Lavacharts

Tags: php, mysql, charts, laravel-5.6

my controller code,

```
 use Khill\Lavacharts\lavacharts;

 $lava=new Lavacharts;
    $stocksTable=$lava->DataTable();
    $stocksTable->addStringColumn('Paper Name')
                ->addNumberColumn('Results');
foreach($papername as $index=>$key)
{
    $stocksTable->addRow([
        $papername[$index],$newscore[$index]
    ]);
}

    $chart=$lava->BarChart('Results',$stocksTable);
    return view('charts',['lava'=>$lava]);
}
```

my view code,

```
<div id="stocks-chart">

</div>
 <?=$lava->render('BarChart', 'resultchart', 'stocks-chart') ?>
```

when executing i get an error,

> "Undefined variable: lava (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lavachartstest\resources\views\charts.blade.php)"

I have also tried using the `Lava` facade, controller code,

```
$stocksTable=\Lava::DataTable();
    $stocksTable->addStringColumn('Paper Name')
                ->addNumberColumn('Results');
foreach($papername as $index=>$key)
{
    $stocksTable->addRow([
        $papername[$index],$newscore[$index]
    ]);
}

    $chart=\Lava::BarChart('Results',$stocksTable);
    return view('charts',['chart'=>$chart]);
}
```

view code

```
<div id="stocks-chart">

</div>
 {!!Lava::render('BarChart', 'resultchart', 'stocks-chart') !!}
```

but still getting error

> "BarChart('resultchart') was not found. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lavachartstest\resources\views\charts.blade.php)"

Comment: Do any of the [examples](http://lavacharts.com/#examples) work? `@areachart('Population', 'pop_div')`

Comment: no it just prints `@areachart('Population', 'pop_div')` on the page